# Input in switch case

Tags: c#

How to not this got showed up when i'm type 5 which mean default

```
Console.Write("Input nilai a = ");
int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Input nilai b = ");
int b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine();
```

This is the source code

```
Console.Write("Input Nomor Menu [1..4]: ");
int pilihan = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine();

Console.Write("Input nilai a = ");
int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Input nilai b = ");
int b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine();


switch (pilihan)
{
    case 1:
        Console.WriteLine("Hasil Penambahan {0} + {1} = {2}", a, b, Penambahan(a, b));
        break;
    case 2:
        Console.WriteLine("Hasil Pengurangan {0} - {1} = {2}", a, b, Pengurangan(a, b));
        break;
    case 3:
        Console.WriteLine("Hasil Perkalian {0} * {1} = {2}", a, b, Perkalian(a, b));
        break;
    case 4:
        Console.WriteLine("Hasil Pembagian {0} / {1} = {2}", a, b, Pembagian(a, b));
        break;           
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Maaf, Menu Yang Anda Pilih Tidak Tersedia"); // Sorry, the Menu You Choose is Not Available
        break;
}
```

Comment: "How to not this got showed up when i'm type 5 which mean default" Eeeeehm, what? That does not make any sense to me. Please explain in detail what you want to achieve and where specifially you´re stuck.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @HimBromBeere most probably OP means typing 5 doesn't heat default case

Comment: If you enter `5` at the first prompt then 2 other numbers `Maaf, Menu Yang Anda Pilih Tidak Tersedia` *will* be printed - what do you see instead?

Comment: I think he wants to hide the input operations and show the error message as soon as you type `5`.

Comment: @AlexK. is probably on to the real problem -- you're typing 5, expecting the "default" message to display, but your program is waiting for you to enter 2 additional numbers

Comment: I'm sorry i can't explain specifically because my bad grammar, but i understand what are you saying, @Gus is right, i expecting the default  message to display, but my program is waiting for me to enter "a" and "b" number

Answer (score 4):

You need to test the menu input *before* printing out the other input prompts:

```
Console.Write("Input Nomor Menu [1..4]: ");
int pilihan = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine();

if (pilihan > 4 || pilihan < 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Maaf, Menu Yang Anda Pilih Tidak Tersedia"); // Sorry, the Menu You Choose is Not Available
}
else
{    
    Console.Write("Input nilai a = ");
    int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.Write("Input nilai b = ");
    int b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine();


    switch (pilihan)
    {
        case 1:
            Console.WriteLine("Hasil Penambahan {0} + {1} = {2}", a, b, Penambahan(a, b));
            break;
        case 2:
            Console.WriteLine("Hasil Pengurangan {0} - {1} = {2}", a, b, Pengurangan(a, b));
            break;
        case 3:
            Console.WriteLine("Hasil Perkalian {0} * {1} = {2}", a, b, Perkalian(a, b));
            break;
        case 4:
            Console.WriteLine("Hasil Pembagian {0} / {1} = {2}", a, b, Pembagian(a, b));
            break;
    }
}
```

You can also skip the default test since you've handled it earlier and you don't want to take any action in that case.

Comment: might need to handle 0 and negative numbers as well

Comment: Yes, but this is the task from my lecturer(?) which is simple and i still freshman in university, i've never tried programming before, i'm sorry @Matt.G

Comment: Oh so you can add "if" too? i've never tried programming before back when i was in high school, actually i have no passion in progamming so i just trying so hard, thank you so much

Comment: Note that this just prints out the error message, and still waits for the additional 2 inputs.  Ideally there would be a `return` or `exit` inside that `if` block.

Comment: @Matt.G good catch. And gus updated - the Stackoverflow mind reader extension seems to have malfunctioned when I was answering (or I got lazy and didn't double-check)

Comment: @ColinYoung my Penambahan, Pengurangan etc is error when i use if from your answer, the error description said that "a" and "b" doesn't exist in the current context, i use like this : static int Penambahan(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }

Comment: Maybe it's because the "static" ?

Comment: Put a break point on the switch statement and examine the variables at that point. I assume your `Penambahan` method is on the same class, and your code is in `static void Main` calling the method, in which case it should be static. I just tested my code and added your static method and it works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

You need to check if the operation `pilihan` is valid before you ask the user for the number inputs. Move the error message from the `default` to the outer `else` clause.

```cs
Console.Write("Input Nomor Menu [1..4]: ");
int pilihan = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine();

if (pilihan > 0 && pilihan < 5)
{
    Console.Write("Input nilai a = ");
    int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.Write("Input nilai b = ");
    int b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine();


    switch (pilihan)
    {
        case 1:
            Console.WriteLine("Hasil Penambahan {0} + {1} = {2}", a, b, 1);
            break;
        case 2:
            Console.WriteLine("Hasil Pengurangan {0} - {1} = {2}", a, b, 2);
            break;
        case 3:
            Console.WriteLine("Hasil Perkalian {0} * {1} = {2}", a, b, 3);
            break;
        case 4:
            Console.WriteLine("Hasil Pembagian {0} / {1} = {2}", a, b, 5);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Maaf, Menu Yang Anda Pilih Tidak Tersedia");
}
```

Comment: might need to handle 0 and negative numbers as well

Comment: @Matt.G Right away, sir!

Comment: Yes, but this is the task from my lecturer(?) which is simple and i still freshman in university, i've never tried programming before, i'm sorry for that, thank you